# Pycharm is still indexing excluded folders and it takes forever

Tags: python, ide, pycharm

I have excluded some data folders using "Mark Directory As" but Pycharm is still indexing them.

I have checked my .iml file which contains my data folders marked as excludeFolder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <module type="PYTHON_MODULE" version="4">
    <component name="NewModuleRootManager">
      <content url="file://$MODULE_DIR$">
        <sourceFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/detectron/detectron/core" isTestSource="false" />
        <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/detectron/detectron/datasets/data" />
        <excludeFolder url="file://$MODULE_DIR$/detectron/models" />
    </content>
    <orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Python 3.6 (pth-1.0.1) (2)" jdkType="Python SDK" />
    <orderEntry type="sourceFolder" forTests="false" />
  </component>
  <component name="TestRunnerService">
    <option name="PROJECT_TEST_RUNNER" value="Unittests" />
  </component>
  </module>
```

Am I missing something?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Does restarting PyCharm help?

Comment: @user2235698 no it doesn't...

Comment: Even though this specific issue is getting old, this kind of issue can arise from time to time and it might be actual bugs like this one being reported https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-57570/PyCharm-indexes-Excluded-nodemodules-directories Worth looking there when this happens.